# Select field or Text field

Tags: html

I have a select with many options. If a user doesn't find value in option, He could fill a "other" field :

```
<select name="value">
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="value">
```

In this case, if I choose a value in the select, it appeared blank beacause of the text fiel.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what your problem is and what you are seeking please.

Comment: why not to use some ready solution like: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: In that example, if a user would have the value "4", he could feel the input text. But if the input text is empty and a value is selected in the select, the result is blank.

Comment: Use <input type="text" required> then the user must enter the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagined it, needs to be improved
http://jsfiddle.net/neiesc/jv6qgn03/

```
<select name="value">
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="chkOther">
    Other
    <input id="chkOther" type="checkbox" value="0" />
</label>
<input id="txtOther" type="text" name="value" disabled>
```

Javascript code:

```
$( "#chkOther" ).click(function() {
    $( "#txtOther" ).prop( "disabled", !$( "#txtOther" ).prop( "disabled"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different names for `select` and `text` input.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="select">
        <option>Choose...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="field">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And in PHP check what was chosen:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // form was sent

    if (!empty($_POST['select'])) {
        // select or both, use select
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['input'])) {
        // empty select txt input filled
    } else {
        // nothing chose in select and text input is blank
    }
}    
?>
```